# retrieving list key with unicode characters in

Tags: python

I have a huge list like below, where i'm trying to access each value. However i have a hard time retrieving `\xe6ndret`, since it has special characters. How can access the column when there is unicode characters in the key?

```
vejstykker = [{u'navngivenvej_id': u'4fb0b0a2-8be7-4254-90d5-fc1af6eb111c', u'kode': u'0007', u'oprettet': u'2019-04-03T13:30:37.031', u'kommunekode': u'0101', u'navn': u'Dompapvej', u'adresseringsnavn': u'Dompapvej', u'\xe6ndret': None, u'id': u'097ae470-9532-4d67-8cb9-6420c601fc24'}]
```

i have tried doing something like below:

```
for vejstykke in vejstykker:
    created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(vejstykke['oprettet'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f');

    id = vejstykke['id']
    kommunekode = vejstykke['kommunekode']
    kode = vejstykke['kode']
    navn = vejstykke['navn']
    adresseringsnavn = vejstykke['adresseringsnavn']
    navngivenvej_id = vejstykke['navngivenvej_id']
    changed_at = vejstykke['ændret']
```

however i get below errror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "", line 28, in run\nKeyError: \'\\xc3\\xa6ndret\'\n'
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Try not to use Python 2, but also `u'ændret'`.

Comment: The ultimate solution to such issues: Python 3.x